# php mysql sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm creating a profile page that will take the id from the url after the user is logged in using the GET method.
but i still get the error message that their are no sessions carried out on the protect pages although the sessions are not empty can anyone help me?

this is a chunk of the code

**profile.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); 
require_once('send_post.php'); 
   session_start();
   $sessionlogin = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $username = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);
    //echo "your do not have a session";
    var_dump($sessionlogin);
   var_dump($userid);
   var_dump($username);
// updatede for using the GET methode for ge the data nedded from the url 
if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
     $userid = $_GET['user_id'];
}
else
{
    echo "this is an error";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `session_start` at the top of the php script, like this

```
<?php
session_start(); //SET SESSION START HERE
ob_start();

require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); 
require_once('send_post.php'); 

$sessionlogin = ($_SESSION['login']);
...
...
...

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the help ...i just want to get the id from the URL can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Your `session_start()` must be included before any headers are output, if there's any output in the two included files, that would cause issues with the session.  Also, I'm curious if your output bufferring is affecting the session.  Try placing `session_start()` above your `ob_start()` call.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **session_start();**  at the starting of page

and one tip if you are using user_id is numeric value

```
if((isset($_GET['user_id']))&&(is_numeric($_GET["user_id"]))) 
 {
   $userid = $_GET['user_id'];
 }
```